# ReactJS & Java: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: java, reactjs, cors

I am making use of axios to fetch data from Java backend and it fails due to cors issue (Please find the attached screenshot). One thing i've noticed is that if i comment out AuthToken part in axios file, it works fine and gives status 200 and if i keep the AuthToken, it breaks cause of cors. Not really sure if the issue is in the java code or is something missing in my axios.js file. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> axios.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://abc.domain.com"
});

instance.defaults.headers.common["AuthToken"] =
"myAuthToken";

export default instance;
```

> headers in .java file

```
 response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE");
 response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, AuthToken");
 response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 response.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

[Cors error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCH9L.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explainatory

> No Access-Controll-Allow-Origin header

You have other headers, true, but not this one.

As for

> One thing i've noticed is that if i comment out AuthToken part in
>   axios file, it works fine and gives status 200 and if i keep the
>   AuthToken,

That is because plain `GET` is considered "simple request" and does not apply to CORS restrictions. When you add additional header to your request, it is no longer simple, and CORS kicks in.

More details about simple requests can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests

Comment: I apologize, i did add Access-Controll-Allow-Origin header please check my edit.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect.  Per your own linked article `application/json` is _not_ a simple request

Comment: @JakeLuby if you would read carefully you would see that `application/json` (technically, lack of it) is regarding `Content-Type`.`Content-Type` defines type of content of request body. You should also know, that GET has no body. In short - you are absolutely incorrect.

Comment: @PzPz so now your screenshot is outdated i guess.

Comment: No it is not, it is still the same. @Antoniossss

Comment: But it says you didnt provide appropriate header while you claim it is otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check out this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

> For requests without credentials, the literal value "*" can be specified, as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error.

As you can see, you are passing a request *with* credentials.  Which is why it works when you omit the token, but doesn't when you add it back in.  The solution is to specify the domain(s) on the java side explicitly, instead of using `*`